# Delete leading zeros on nginx config variables

Tags: string, nginx

I would like to know if it is possible to remove leading zeros on variables on nginx config files.

I have a variable defined as follows:

```
set $definitive_var $var1$var2$var3$var4;
```

And a map to get $var1, $var2, $var3 and $var4 value:

```
map $arg_a $var1 {
8JaYh7s733  0;
EMFnZiHXp4  1;
GWpn69jI0Z  2;
3eLtv4qOWj  3;
I7k80VJ1iH  4;
b2y36c342K  5;
qGi45WCfJA  6;
90y6i5H71b  7;
MQ02jOzoay  8;
curR6p449h  9;}
```

My question is:

In case variable $definitive_var would have one or more leading zeros, how could I remove them?

For exemple, convert:

```
0076
```

to:

```
76
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
map $def_var $definitive_var {
  ~^0*(\d*)$ $1;
}

...

set $def_var $var1$var2$var3$var4;

...

# use $defnitive_var here, it will be automatically calculated from $def_var
```

**Update**

If your variable may only consists of zeroes, to prevent mapping of `'00000'` to `''`, change the regular expression to `~^0*(\d+)$`.

Comment: I got the following error with the map: nginx: [emerg] unknown "1" variable

Comment: @JosepAntoniCostaCamps Just copy-pasted and checked this config, everything is ok. It is considered a good practice to [avoid](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) `if` constructions whithin nginx configs.

Comment: Which nginx version are you using? Mine is 1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: @JosepAntoniCostaCamps Mine is 1.14.1 (CentOS 6). Maybe this is really a problem with an old version of nginx, can't test this. My test config contains all above `map` definitions and `location / { set $def_var $var1$var2$var3$var4; return 302 /var/$definitive_var; }`. `curl -I "my.domain.net?a=8JaYh7s733&b=EMFnZiHXp4&c=8JaYh7s733"` gives me `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Location: http://my.domain.net/var/10`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it using an if:

```
set $def_var $var1$var2$var3$var4;

if ( $def_var ~ "^0*(\d+)$" ) {
    set $definitive_var $1;
}
```

Thanks for your help!